# Copying data between tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I need to copy records from `DeCategories` to `Categories` (about 1.7 million) along with "processing" (new slug etc).

Category use: https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset

The following script works fine, but works for many days. How to optimize / make it work faster? I am beginner in Laravel.

I have this models

```
class DeCategories extends Model
{
    use ScopeActiveTrait;

    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['category_name', 'description', 'keywords', 'content', 'enable', 'photo', 'order', 'slug', '_lft', '_rgt', 'parent_id'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $table = 'cms_multikategorie22';
}



class Category extends Model
{
    use ScopeActiveTrait;
    use NodeTrait;
    use Slugable;

    public function setCategoryNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['category_name'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = $this->makeSlug($value);
    }

    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['category_name', 'description', 'keywords', 'content', 'enable', 'photo', 'order', 'slug', '_lft', '_rgt', 'parent_id'];
    public $timestamps = false;

}

trait Slugable
{
    protected function makeSlug($value)
    {
        $slug = str_slug($value);

        $count = static::whereRaw("slug RLIKE '^{$slug}(-[0-9]+)?$'")->count();

        return $count ? "{$slug}-{$count}" : $slug;
    }
}

trait ScopeActiveTrait
{
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('enable', 1);
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        echo 'Importuje <br/>';
        //die();
        $level1 = DeCategories::where('title', "<>", '')->where('parent_id', 325193)->get();
        if (!$level1->isEmpty()) {
            foreach ($level1 as $key1 => $value1) {
                echo $value1->title . "<br/>";

                ////////
                $slug = str_slug($value1->title);
                $next = 1;
                while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->exists()) {
                    $next++;
                    $slug = str_slug($value1->title . '-' . $next);
                }
                ////////

                $category = new Category();
                $category->category_name = $value1->title;
                $category->description = $value1->title;
                $category->keywords = $value1->title;
                $category->content = $value1->id . '-1';
                $category->enable = 1;
                $category->photo = '';
                $category->order = $value1->position;
                $category->parent_id = 0;
                $category->slug = $slug;
                $category->save();
                $id1 = $category->id;


                $level2 = DeCategories::where('parent_id', $value1->id)->get();
                //dump($level2);
                if (!$level2->isEmpty()) {
                    foreach ($level2 as $key2 => $value2) {

                        ////////
                        $slug2 = str_slug($value2->title);
                        $next2 = 1;
                        while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug2)->exists()) {
                            $next2++;
                            $slug2 = str_slug($value2->title . '-' . $next2);
                        }
                        ////////
                        $category2 = new Category();
                        $category2->category_name = $value2->title;
                        $category2->description = $value2->title;
                        $category2->keywords = $value2->title;
                        $category2->content = $value2->id . '-2';
                        $category2->enable = 1;
                        $category2->photo = '';
                        $category2->order = $value2->position;
                        $category2->parent_id = $id1;
                        $category2->slug = $slug2;
                        $category2->save();

                        $id2 = $category2->id;


                        $level3 = DeCategories::where('parent_id', $value2->id)->get();
                        if (!$level3->isEmpty()  && $value2->id !=""  && $value2->id != null) {
                            foreach ($level3 as $key3 => $value3) {
                                ////////
                                $slug3 = str_slug($value3->title);
                                $next3 = 1;
                                while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug3)->exists()) {
                                    $next3++;
                                    $slug3 = str_slug($value3->title . '-' . $next3);
                                }
                                ////////

                                $category3 = new Category();
                                $category3->category_name = $value3->title;
                                $category3->description = $value3->title;
                                $category3->keywords = $value3->title;
                                $category3->content = $value3->id . '-3';
                                $category3->enable = 1;
                                $category3->photo = '';
                                $category3->order = $value3->position;
                                $category3->parent_id = $id2;
                                $category3->slug = $slug3;
                                $category3->save();

                                $id3 = $category3->id;


                                $level4 = DeCategories::where('parent_id', $value3->id)->get();
                                if (!$level4->isEmpty()   && $value3->id !=""  && $value3->id != null) {
                                    foreach ($level4 as $key4 => $value4) {

                                        ////////
                                        $slug4 = str_slug($value4->title);
                                        $next4 = 1;
                                        while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug4)->exists()) {
                                            $next4++;
                                            $slug4 = str_slug($value4->title . '-' . $next4);
                                        }
                                        ////////
                                        $category4 = new Category();
                                        $category4->category_name = $value4->title;
                                        $category4->description = $value4->title;
                                        $category4->keywords = $value4->title;
                                        $category4->content = $value4->id . '-4';
                                        $category4->enable = 1;
                                        $category4->photo = '';
                                        $category4->order = $value4->position;
                                        $category4->parent_id = $id3;
                                        $category4->slug = $slug4;
                                        $category4->save();

                                        $id4 = $category4->id;


                                        $level5 = DeCategories::where('parent_id', $value4->id)->get();
                                        if (!$level5->isEmpty()   && $value4->id !=""  && $value4->id != null) {
                                            foreach ($level5 as $key5 => $value5) {

                                                $slug5 = str_slug($value5->title);
                                                $next5 = 1;
                                                while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug5)->exists()) {
                                                    $next5++;
                                                    $slug5 = str_slug($value5->title . '-' . $next5);
                                                }
                                                $category5 = new Category();
                                                $category5->category_name = $value5->title;
                                                $category5->description = $value5->title;
                                                $category5->keywords = $value5->title;
                                                $category5->content = $value5->id . '-5';
                                                $category5->enable = 1;
                                                $category5->photo = '';
                                                $category5->order = $value5->position;
                                                $category5->parent_id = $id4;
                                                $category5->slug = $slug5;
                                                $category5->save();

                                                $id5 = $category5->id;

                                                $level6 = DeCategories::where('parent_id', $value5->id)->get();
                                                if (!$level6->isEmpty()   && $value5->id !=""  && $value5->id != null) {
                                                    foreach ($level6 as $key6 => $value6) {

                                                        $slug6 = str_slug($value6->title);
                                                        $next6 = 1;
                                                        while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug6)->exists()) {
                                                            $next6++;
                                                            $slug6 = str_slug($value6->title . '-' . $next6);
                                                        }
                                                        $category6 = new Category();
                                                        $category6->category_name = $value6->title;
                                                        $category6->description = $value6->title;
                                                        $category6->keywords = $value6->title;
                                                        $category6->content = $value6->id . '-6';
                                                        $category6->enable = 1;
                                                        $category6->photo = '';
                                                        $category6->order = $value6->position;
                                                        $category6->parent_id = $id5;
                                                        $category6->slug = $slug6;
                                                        $category6->save();

                                                        $id6 = $category6->id;


                                                        $level7 = DeCategories::where('parent_id', $value6->id)->get();
                                                        if (!$level7->isEmpty()  && $value6->id !=""  && $value6->id != null) {
                                                            foreach ($level7 as $key7 => $value7) {

                                                                $slug7 = str_slug($value7->title);
                                                                $next7 = 1;
                                                                while (Category::where('slug', '=', $slug7)->exists()) {
                                                                    $next7++;
                                                                    $slug7 = str_slug($value7->title . '-' . $next7);
                                                                }
                                                                $category7 = new Category();
                                                                $category7->category_name = $value7->title;
                                                                $category7->description = $value7->title;
                                                                $category7->keywords = $value7->title;
                                                                $category7->content = $value7->id . '-7';
                                                                $category7->enable = 1;
                                                                $category7->photo = '';
                                                                $category7->order = $value7->position;
                                                                $category7->parent_id = $id6;
                                                                $category7->slug = $slug7;
                                                                $category7->save();

                                                            }
                                                        }


                                                    }
                                                }


                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        echo 'finish';
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it works many days" ? Also, what version of Laravel are you using ? 7 or 5. Chose one, not both.

Answer (score 0):

For this quantity, IMO, you shouldn't use Models. They are heavy and this case it's taking huge time. Instead, use `DB::table('x')->...`.

For dealing with the slug, I recommend the cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable. Give it a try ;)

You will see a tremendous reduce on execution time, just by doing that.

Comment: is faster https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable than traditional slug?

Comment: It queries the db to create a unique slug based on a title. Your while() would be replaced by a single line.